# How does the Unit Test log/report work?

Tags: php, unit-testing

I'm new at unit test so please be patient. I'm following this good [tutorial](http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-models/2010/10/).

Using this configuration file

```
log type="coverage-html" 
target="./log/report" 
charset="UTF-8" 
yui="true" 
highlight="true" 
lowUpperBound="50" 
highLowerBound="80"/>
log type="testdox-html" 
target="./log/testdox.html"/
```

I realized that the `testdox.html` is auto generated but in the tutorial code there is also
a lot of files in log/report (not auto generated) so I'm wondering how that stuff works and how to set it up and above all where it comes from?